# How to show that $(8+\epsilon)^{1/3}-2 < 2 - (8-\epsilon)^{1/3}$ for $\epsilon>0$ without invoking concepts from advanced calculus incl. derivatives?

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

Using the classical $(\delta, \epsilon)$ definition of the limit of a function, I need to prove that $(8+\epsilon)^{1/3}-2 < 2 - (8-\epsilon)^{1/3}$ for $\epsilon>0$.

> By invoking the concept of derivative, it can easily be show that $f(\epsilon) = (8+\epsilon)^{1/3} + (8-\epsilon)^{1/3}-4$ is a monotonically decreasing function of $\epsilon$, thus readily leading to the desired inequality.

I was wondering whether this is a trick to demonstrate that inequality without calling on the concept of derivative.

Any hints are highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That's actually the property $$f\left ({x+y\over 2}\right )>{f(x)+f(y)\over 2},\quad 0<x<y$$ for $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ and $x=8-\varepsilon,$ $y=8+\varepsilon.$ I believe the inequality could be proved applying $$a-b={a^3-b^3\over a^2+ab+b^2}$$ Just plug in $a=(x+y)/2$, $b=x$ and $a=y$, $b=(x+y)/2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=(8-\varepsilon)^{1/3}$ and $b=(8+\varepsilon)^{1/3}.$    Then $$2-a={2^3-a^3\over 4+2a+a^2}={\varepsilon\over 4+2a+a^2}$$
$$b-2={b^3-2^3\over 4+2b+b^2}={\varepsilon\over 4+2b+b^2}$$ We have $b>a$ hence $2-a>b-2.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(2 + r)$ denote $(8 + \epsilon)^{(1/3)}.$ 
Let $(2 - s)$ denote $(8 - \epsilon)^{(1/3)}.$ 
Clearly, $~0 < r,s.$

Then, the problem reduces to showing that $r < s$.

$(8 + \epsilon) = (2 + r)^3 = 8 + 12r + 6r^2 + r^3 \implies$ 
$\epsilon = 12r + 6r^2 + r^3.$

$(8 - \epsilon) = (2 - s)^3 = 8 - 12s + 6s^2 - s^3 \implies$ 
$\epsilon = 12s - 6s^2 + s^3.$

Therefore, 
$12r + 6r^2 + r^3 = 12s - 6s^2 + s^3 \implies $

$$12(s-r) - 6(s^2 + r^2) + (s^3 - r^3) = 0. \tag1 $$

Suppose $s \leq r.$

Then, in (1) above, the 1st and 3rd terms are non-positive and the 2nd term is negative.  This yields a contradiction.

Therefore, it is not the case that $s \leq r.$